# Test interaction between flask apps

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, python-unittest

I have a flask app that is intended to be hosted on multiple host. That is, the same app is running on different hosts. Each host can then send a request to the others host to take some action on the it's respective system.

For example, assume that there is systems A and B both running this flask app. A knows the IP address of B and the port number that the app is hosted on B. A gets a request via a POST intended for B. A then needs to forward this request to B.

I have the forwarding being done in a route that simply checks the JSON attached to the POST to see if it is the intended host. If not is uses python's requests library to make a POST request to the other host.

My issue is how do I simulate this environment (two different instance of the same app with different ports) in a python unittest so I can confirm that the forwarding is done correctly?

Right now I am using the app.test_client() to test most of the routes but as far as I can tell the app.test_client() does not contain a port number or IP address associated with it. So having the app POST to another app.test_client() seems unlikely.

I tried hosting the apps in different threads but there does not seem to be a clean and easy way to kill the thread once app.run() starts, can't join as app.run() never exits. In addition, the internal state of the app (app.config) would be hidden. This makes verifying that A does not do the request and B does hard.

Is there any way to run two flask app simultaneously on different port numbers and still get access to both app's app.config? Or am I stuck using the threads and finding some other way to make sure A does not execute the request and B does?

Note: these app do not have any forums so there is no CSRF.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing two things. One, I started using patch decorator from the mock library to fake the response form systems B. More specifically I use the @patch('requests.post') then in my code I set the return value to "< Response [200]>". However this only makes sure that requests.post is called, not that the second system processed it correctly. The second thing I did was write a separate test that makes the request that should have been sent by A and sends it to the system to check if it processes it correctly. In this manner systems A and B are never running at the same time. Instead the tests just fake there responses/requests.

In summery, I needed to use @patch('requests.post') to fake the reply from B saying it got the request. Then, in a different test, I set up B and made a request to it.